# VSFTPD Virtual User Group

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, vsftpd

Currently I have a Running vsftpd server in a Cent OS Machine with virtual users.

Users are authenticated using MySQL.

The users has all the permissions in their home directory and they are jailed into their home directories. The current home directory is /home/vsftpd/username where username is the unique username for each user. It is working file.

Now I want to create some new virtual or real users which will have another kind of home directories i.e. /var/www/html/username.

I want to keep both types of users in the same server. I mean I need both the old users with the old home directories and new ones with the different home directories in the same vsftpd server.

I have gone through many tutorial but found nothing.

So please let me know if is it possible,if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this and control by user's permission. try to explore the following commands

1. vim /etc/passwd ==> user's home directory and executable shell etc...
2. vim /etc/groups or group ==> user's group information and modify your convenient
3. chmod & chown commands will let you access directories

Thanks,
Ela

Comment: VSFTPD has it's own passwd file, is it possible to edit these settings in /etc/passwd file??!!